# How transform timestamp to date string 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' use JoltTransformJson in nifi

Tags: datetime, timestamp, apache-nifi, jolt

I have this JSON with field the `createdAt`:

```json
{
  "_id": "ir9RHG9nWqYAytwir",
  "userId": "rv4M5xfbz5wmugewp",
  "type": "online",
  "createdAt": 1684850821122
}
```

I want to get next JSON use JOLT specification in apache nifi

```json
{
  "_id": "ir9RHG9nWqYAytwir",
  "userId": "rv4M5xfbz5wmugewp",
  "type": "online",
  "createdAt": '2023-05-22 14:05:33'
}
```

expected output:

```json
{
  "_id": "ir9RHG9nWqYAytwir",
  "userId": "rv4M5xfbz5wmugewp",
  "type": "online",
  "createdAt": '2023-05-22 14:05:33'
}
```

i use next jolt specification:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "createdAt": "${createdAt:toDate('yyyy-MM-ddHH:mm:ss'):format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')}"
    }
  }
]
```

Which does not work

Comment: can you provide an [mre] and what have you tried so far?

Comment: i used "=toDate(@(1,createdAt),'timestamp') | format('yyyy-MM-dd'),

Comment: do you get any errors or ?

Comment: maybe this can help you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/52642215/936269

Comment: not work {
  "_id" : "ir9RHG9nWqYAytwir",
  "userId" : "rv4M5xfbz5wmugewp",
  "type" : "online",
  "createdAt" : "${createdAt:toDate('yyyy-MM-ddHH:mm:ss')}"
} i get this json

Comment: what jolt function to use to convert date from number to date string?

Comment: There's no such function unfortunately

Comment: and when to convert a date from a number to a date string using JoltTransfrormJson or UpdateAttribute?

Comment: I think using an `UpdateAttribute` along with **expression language** would rather be more suitable